# how to export saved goals in PES 2013 to gif

Tags: pro-evolution-soccer-2013

What is the most convenient way (i.e. require minimum effort) to export my saved goals in PES 2013 to gifs?

Comment: Most likely the Print Screen button, I would assume.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [FRAPS](http://www.fraps.com/) to capture the game's video and audio output, then convert the video into an animated GIF using something like the [Free Video to GIF Converter](http://www.video-gif-converter.com/).